# Should I keep frontend code in src/main folder in Spring Boot projects?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, angular, spring-boot

I have no fullstack code experience with Spring Boot and I am wondering what is the most proper way or common approach for keeping frontend code in Spring Boot projects.

So, should I create a folder called `frontend` under `src/main` and keep Angular or React code in this directory as shown below?

```
- my-app-name
   |
   -- src
       |
       -- main
            |
            ---- frontend
            ---- java
            ---- resources
```

Or should I prefer `src/main/resource` ?

Comment: are you hosting your angular app from your spring boot app? I would keep it separate and host it separately as well, it's just a static javascript anyway

Comment: @Pavel Very good point, but as I have not previous experience, I missed that point. So, what would you suggest? I am also considering GitHub repository and would like to keep frontend and backend project in the same repo. So, should I also separete these 2 projects to 2 repositories?

Comment: usually, if frontend is not a part of your java application, it should go to a separate repo or a separate directory like my-app-name-backend/ and my-app-name-frontend/

Comment: @voismager That is actually what I have done so far. I use a root directory with `my-app-name` and created 2 directories in it with `frontend` and `backend`. Then keep the root directory into a single repository. So, is it a good approach? What would you suggest extra?

Comment: @Pavel Any idea about my reply for your comment?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, but I believe you'll find that most of us would not bundle the UI with the spring-boot jar unless that UI is dependent on spring-boot, e.g. a template engine like Thymeleaf.  In my opinion, I'd have the UI off in its own separate project.  Separate the projects, you'll make things easier for yourself.

Comment: @lane.maxwell Thank you so much for these good explanations. Now I understood the idea completely and will follow this approach. Then, I think it is good to create 2 separate GitHub repository for these 2 projects and name them as `my-app-frontend` and `my-app-backend`, right? May I get your opinion for that?

Comment: @lane.maxwell Chico? Any reply please?

Comment: @william absolutely.  I usually name mine something like API and UI.  If the project were for tracking widgets, I'd have a widgets-api repository and widgest-ui repository.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already pointed out by multiple people in the comments, you should bundle the frontend and backend separately. The reason for this is also that you need to build, package and deploy them separately and you need a separate pipeline for each of them. For example your spring boot app will be built as a docker container and deployed to kubernetes while it does not make much sense to host the frontend in such way, it could be hosted in a CDN.

This leaves us with your second point - monorepo vs multiple repositories. Both have their pros and cons. You can find a lot of articles on this topic online. I assume, that this is a small project and you'll work on both frontend and backend by yourself at once. In such case, you can do very well with the monorepo approach. You can do a change across both frontend and backend in a single commit, the refactoring will be easier etc. But if you choose to go with mutliple repositories, there is nothing wrong with it.

One more thing to consider is where and how you'll manage your API contract between the frontend and backend. There are again multiple approaches here. I'd advise not to go without the API contract specs (like doing everything by hand on both server and client side) and in case you go with monorepo don't create your dependency between the frontend and backend directly (on the file level), that create unecessarry coupling between those two.

Comment: Veeerry very good explanations. Only one point that I would like tı ask.  I use Swagger and already known some examples. Regarding to API contract, do you mean that **creating REST API and its documentation and call these endpoints from frontend side even both projects are in the same repo**?

Comment: By the way, I  could not vote up as I have not enough repo. Any vote up pls for the question?

Comment: there are again many options here as well. also depending on whether you want to follow spec first or code first approach, meaning if you write your api specs first and use it to generate code or vice versa. I am more in to spec first approach, you can for example define your api specs and publish in swaggerhub and then based on that generate your server stubs in the backend spring boot app and the client in the frontend. 
(btw. you should be always able to accept the answer, if it sufficiently answers your question)

Comment: I will, but you did not replied my question related to "API contract". I already generate swagger, but you still mentioned on it instead my question.

Comment: sorry mate, I missed that one. if you already generate the api contract, you can add client generation based on that contract to your frontend app. you would have to reflect this dependency into your pipeline as well - first generate api contract and in the next stage generate the client library

Comment: Do you mean that generate API documentation (swagger, etc.) for backend and then generate a similar one for frontend?

Comment: I mean generate the client library in the frontend from the api specs, something like https://medium.com/sohoffice/the-api-first-strategy-use-swagger-to-generate-api-client-as-an-angular-library-66964ea43587